# How to transpose specific cell values in a row based on "Y" or "N" input

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, transpose

The ultimate goal is to set the status of a particular row to "Yes" and have the data of that row that is highlighted RED automatically be entered into another sheet in order to be printed in a format required for a Zlabel printer.

If you can imagine this raw data on a larger scale and having to print 50+ rows daily. I do this manually now but really hoping to streamline this process [image: Pic 1]

This is how I'm hoping the data will look on a separate sheet when the status is set to "Yes" regardless of how many rows there are I could print in bulk [image: Pic 2]

Open to any other suggestions that may include VBA macros or any other recommended solutions.

Any advice or help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Since you are looking for an automation therefore the best suitable method is VBA macro,, if you are comfortable with handling macro then [edit] the post & add line all about using Macro also add new TAG, VBA/vba to the question.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create the [label in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-print-labels-82086c07-2afa-4982-9d7d-9c9141d5035b) and then [combine it with your excel file.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/prepare-your-excel-data-source-for-a-word-mail-merge-2d802b6b-a3a3-43e5-bb76-2cac7c68673e). No VBA needed!

Comment: Is `Yes` manually written into the cells or is there a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1) 'Data sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2)  'Result sheet
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    
    For i = 1 To r
        If vDB(i, 9) = "Yes" Then
            n = n + 5
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n - 4) = vDB(i, 1)
            vR(n - 3) = vDB(i, 4)
            vR(n - 2) = vDB(i, 5)
            vR(n - 1) = vDB(i, 7)
        End If
    Next i
    
    With toWs
        .UsedRange = Empty
        .Range("a1").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy By Criteria

- The following **automatically** clears the contents of the **Target Worksheet**
  ("`Sheet2`") and copies all data specified by **Crit** ("`Yes`") to
  it ("`Sheet2`"), when any data in the **Criteria Column** ("`I`") of
  the **Source Worksheet** ("`Sheet1`") is **manually** changed (i.e.
  it could be written to run more efficiently).
- If you don't want it to run automatically, then remove the code from
  the **Sheet Module** and just run the first `Sub` (maybe using a
  button) when needed (which was my first idea).
- You can change `tgtGap`, the number of rows in between data blocks.
- You can add or remove columns to the `Cols` array.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const CriteriaColumn As Variant = "I"  ' e.g. "A" or 1

Sub copyByCriteria()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Crit As String = "Yes"
    Dim Cols As Variant: Cols = Array("A", "D", "E", "G") ' or 1, 4, 5, 7
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const tgtGap As Long = 1
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Collect data from Source Worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim Criteria As Variant
    getColumn Criteria, ws, CriteriaColumn, FirstRow
    If IsEmpty(Criteria) Then Exit Sub
    Dim ubC As Long: ubC = UBound(Criteria)
    Dim ubD As Long: ubD = UBound(Cols)
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(ubD)
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To ubD
        Data(j) = ws.Cells(FirstRow, Cols(j)).Resize(ubC)
    Next j
    Dim critCount As Long
    critCount = Application.WorksheetFunction _
                           .CountIf(ws.Columns(CriteriaColumn), Crit)
    
    ' Write data from Data Arrays to Target Array.
    Dim Target As Variant, i As Long, k As Long
    ReDim Target(1 To critCount * (ubD + 1 + tgtGap) - tgtGap, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To ubC
        If Criteria(i, 1) = Crit Then
            For j = 0 To ubD
                k = k + 1
                Target(k, 1) = Data(j)(i, 1)
            Next j
            k = k + tgtGap
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write Target Array to Target Worksheet.
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    ws.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Target)).Value = Target
    
End Sub

Sub getColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
              Sheet As Worksheet, _
              Optional aColumn As Variant = 1, _
              Optional FirstRow As Long = 1)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(aColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row > FirstRow Then
        Data = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, aColumn), rng).Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(CriteriaColumn)) Is Nothing Then
        copyByCriteria
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel O365, then you could also opt for a formula. If your data has to start in `Sheet2!A1` onwards then in `A1`:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),5)>0,INDEX(INDEX(FILTER(Sheet1!A:H,Sheet1!I:I="Yes"),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(Sheet1!I:I,"Yes")),{1;4;5;7}),ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0),MOD(ROW(),5)),"")
```

Drag down.